# A line between coordinates wicketstuff openlayers3

Tags: java, wicket, openlayers, openlayers-3, wicketstuff

I've been looking around for a while for a solution to draw a line between two points on a openlayers 3 map in openlayers 3 wicketstuff, but can't seem to find any solution. Is there a simple way to do this?